# sending an email notification to the administrator after form submission

Tags: drupal

I have created a form using content type in and have created a custom module with the with the code below to send an email notification to the admin after the form has been submitted.

```
<?php


$params = array(
    'subject' => "New submission",
    'body' => "<p>Hello world</p>",
    );

//send out the e-mail,
drupal_mail('admin_email_notification', 'admin_email_notification_example', "admin@gmail.com", language_default(), $params);
drupal_set_message("Sent e-mail to admin@gmail.com"); 

/** Implementing the hook_mail()**/

function admin_email_notification_mail($key, &$message, $params)
{
    //Grab the subject and body from params and add it to the messsage.
    $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
    $message['body'][] = $params['body'];

    switch($key)
    {
        case "admin_email_notification_example":

        break;
    }
}


function admin_email_notification_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    t($form['#submit'], 'admin_email_notification_custom_submission');
}

function admin_email_notification_custom_submission(&$form, $form_state)
{
    $params = array(
    'subject' => "New submission",
    'body' => "<p>Hello world</p>",
    );

    //send out the e-mail,
    drupal_mail('admin_email_notification', 'admin_email_notification_example', "admin@gmail.com", language_default(), $params);
    drupal_set_message("Sent e-mail to admin@gmail.com"); 

}
```

For the module to work I had to commet line 413 in mail.inc since I was receiving an error message saying Call to undefined function _filter_htmlcorrector() in .../drupal_folder/includes/mail.inc. The admin is now receiving an email after the form submission. 
But the problem is even after any kind of action for example refresshing of a page the admin is receiving an email.
Is there a way I can use to include a rule in the code that only sets a restriction of sending a mail to the admin iff the form has been submitted . And  I also want the module to work perfectly well without me commenting the the line which contains _filter_htmlcorrector() in mail.inc.

Comment: call the drupal_mail function in your form submit handler :)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that

Comment: take a look at my comment below

Comment: Thank you very much Elendas I'm going to definitely include that in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your module (assuming it is called 'admin_email_notification'):

```
// First, add an extra submit function to your node/add form, where FORM_ID is the id of your form.
function admin_email_notification_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'admin_email_notification_custom_submission');
}

// Next, the extra submit function, where you can, for example, send your mails
function admin_email_notification_custom_submission(&$form, $form_state) {
  $params = array(
    'subject' => "New submission",
    'body' => "<p>Hello world</p>",
    );

  //send out the e-mail,
  drupal_mail('admin_email_notification', 'admin_email_notification_example', "admin@gmail.com", language_default(), $params);
  drupal_set_message("Sent e-mail to admin@gmail.com"); 
}
```

Comment: I have included the code but the module is still performing the same way, sending email everytime I refresh a page as well as form submission . Might it be that I have placed the code snippet on a wrong position?

Comment: Can you add the code of your module to your question, including the name of your module and content-type? PS: always flush your cache to make sure the new functions are recognised.

Comment: I have added your code below the first code in my module and still there is no difference. the name of my module is admin_email_notification and the content type name is posts then the machine name for the content_type is send_email.